# Vertical CSS timeline steady markup

Tags: css, markup, timeline

**Description:**
Have vertical timeline for `12 hours` day.
 Height is `720px`.
From the first glance markup should look like:

```
<div style="margin-top:0px;">
 9:00
</div>
<div style="margin-top:60px;">
 10:00
</div>
       ...
<div style="margin-top:60px;">
 11:00
</div>
```

It's occured,that we should take into consideration `font-size`.
As it's more,than less should be the value of `margin-top` property.

**Demo:**
[see markup](http://jsfiddle.net/fmSfc/1/)
For current font-size value of `margin-top` is `38px`
Logically,it should be always equal to `60px`.

**Question:**
Is there `CSS` solution without `JS` for vertical timilene,which doesn't depend upon `font-size`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you want. But I suspect you'd like to ensure equally spaced divisions of the timeline.

You don't need to compensate for font-size with margin-top. Remove those inline styles and simply fix the height of the divs with

```
.timeline-container > div{
   height:60px;   
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/fmSfc/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use constant line-height - You will be able to change font-size without changing margin-top and overall height. Check the update : http://jsfiddle.net/fmSfc/6/

Also, it would be better to use unsorted list then divs, as you have many listed similar elements.